# Calculating many shortest paths with pgRouting

Tags: qgis, pgrouting

I have 145013 Danish addresses, and 10 big cities in Denmark as points in QGIS. Furthermore, I have four vector layers that connect all the points. They are small roads, main roads, freeways and ferry routes. See the screen dump from QGIS below for an illustration:

[image: QGIS screen dump illustrating my problem]

Now I would like to calculate the shortest distance from each address to each of the 10 big cities. I will use pgRouting for this, and I have followed the tutorial on finding 1 shortest path at http://anitagraser.com/2013/07/06/pgrouting-2-0-for-windows-quick-guide/

However, I can't figure out how to extend the problem from 1 path to (145013 * 10 =) 1450130 paths.

What method should I use in pgRouting, and how do I incorporate all the 1450130 paths?

I use:

- QGIS 2.1.0
- postgres 9.2
- postgis 2.0
- pgRouting 2.0
- OS: Win 7 64bit

I have shared my data here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rn8gdxr1bki4q4x/fFRd0PerkP

It's in a QGIS project file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First load data into postgis and convert all data to same projection. Create one table from all data and   follow PgRouting tutorial to create  edges and vertexes. I really hope that that data is topologically correct already and you dont need to fix those issues. ( Have you considered just using osm2po data for your network ? )

If you have already done it, then see [pgrouting dijkstra example](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/shortest_path.html#shortest-path-dijkstra) and do:

This works but is slow. i used Finnish osm2po data for testing

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_routes(target int) RETURNS VOID  AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    r record; 

BEGIN

    CREATE TABLE route_res as  SELECT  0 , route.* 
        FROM (SELECT  seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost FROM pgr_dijkstra('
                SELECT gid AS id,
                         source::integer,
                         target::integer,
                         length::double precision AS cost
                        FROM vw_finland_routing',
               10 , 60, false, false) ) as route  ; 



    FOR r IN
        SELECT source from vw_finland_routing
    LOOP

      INSERT INTO route_res  SELECT  r.source , route.* 
        FROM (SELECT  seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost FROM pgr_dijkstra('
                SELECT gid AS id,
                         source::integer,
                         target::integer,
                         length::double precision AS cost
                        FROM vw_finland_routing',
               r.source  , target, false, false) ) as route ; 

        RAISE NOTICE  ' Running at % source id' ,r.source ;
    END LOOP;

END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

AND

```
SELECT get_all_routes(10) -- where 10 is target from city
```

Solution is slow and badly written. CREATE table needs to be taken out from function or  needs to be in if exist block. to get some performance out of this you need to run N queries to target or if you can change it so that source is city and target is in for loop. My other ideas for problem are using `pgr_kDijkstra`. Or you can create city wide polygon and use it to overwrite that area source/target id's so function needs only find an area (takes 1000-> or more edges from route table)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have imported all data into QGIS, and I have merged all the roads to 1 layer, but I'm unsure what to do with the addresses and big cities (start and end points of my paths). Should these layers be merged with the road layer and imported into a postgis table, or should I have 3 tables; one for the roads, one for the start points, and one for the end points?

Comment: you need to have "target" id:s in routes layer´? Have you used  pgr_createTopology('<table>', float tolerance, '<geometry column', '<gid>') ?

Comment: but my targets are points and the roads are lines. I thought it wasn't possible to merge these to one layer.

Comment: And yes I have run pgr_createTopology(roads, 0.000001, geom, id)

Comment: Having looked at your answer, I think my biggest problem is how/where I define the sources (addresses in my dataset)? I don't want shortest path from all places on the roads, but only the places where there is an address

Comment: ahh.. you need to find closes road for point (that will be your source id ), (slow query) "select r.sourceid, address.id , st_distance(r.geom, address.geom) into all_sources order by select st_distance(r.geom, address.geom) ASC limit 1" then you in plpgsql function you replace for r in .. with : "for r in select source from all_sources"

Comment: Thanks for the effort and please excuse my slow and limited understanding of GIS data. I am running the query to find the closest roads right now. Am I correct in that you miss a parentheses around the 2nd select ending before ASC?

Comment: i missed whole "from roads as r , address" part, correct(i hope) sql would be: select r.sourceid, a.id, st_distance(r.geom, a.geom) into all_sources from roads r , address a WHERE st_dwithing(r.geom, a.geom, 1000) ORDER BY st_distance(r.geom, a.geom) ASC LIMIT 1" Where ST_Dwithin(..) makes it use slow ST_Distance only to geoms within 10km (assuming that you use projection which uses meters), Note: i may have used r.geom and a.geom in wrong order. double check in http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/

Comment: The select to find the nearest road to each point above didn't work as it should. It just returned 1 row and took 1000 minutes to run. Is there no easy "snap" function to do this?

Comment: Inspired by your idea and looking online I thought of using the following select to find the source ids:Select ST_Closestpoint(ST_Collect(a.geom), b.geom) as geom
from roads a inner join addresses b
on ST_Dwithin(a.geom, b.geom, 1000)
group by b.id, b.geom; Wouldn't that do it?

Comment: my sql almoust work. Select * from road r, address a ORDER BY ST_Distance(r.geom, a.geom) that will return all roads geoms distance to all addresses. that limit 1 changes it so that it only return shortest distance. There is some smarter way, but you could re-use that plpgsql script and do for loop again but on address table and change SQL to " SELECT ro.id, r.id  from roads as ro WHERE ST_Dwithin(r.geom, ro.geom, 1000) ORDER BY ST_Distance(r.geom, ro.geom) ASC LIMIT 1" (r as record from select * from address ) you should have now table with road.id and address.id which are closest

Comment: Okay. I am using the following select to get the nearest road to each of the 10 cities: "SELECT DISTINCT ON(h.id) h.id as id_city, b.*into snap_cities
FROM roads b INNER JOIN cities h 
ON ST_DWithin(h.geom, b.geom, 1000)
ORDER BY h.id, ST_Distance(b.geom, h.geom);" And i will also use this select for the addresses, and then try to use ur function together with `pgr_kdjikstraCost()`

Answer (score 4):

You can use a new algorithm of pgRouting 2.0 nammed `pgr_kDijkstra`.
It will allow you to request "1-n" shortest paths with a single query.

There are two variations: one returns the full path of all routes and one only returns the total cost for each route.

The documentation should explain how to use it: http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/src/kdijkstra/doc/index.html#pgr-kdijkstra