# How to calculate the shortest distance for multiple source and targets using PgRouting?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, network, route

I have a table with points and a road network which includes driveways (where you enter the highway).

I want to find the point which is closest to a driveway. So I was thinking I can calculate the distance from all the points to all the driveways (maybe within a specific boundary). And from there I can find which point is closest to a driveway. I have joined the points with the network, so I know which ‘source’ I can use from the network. I also know the ‘targets’.

And I can calculate the distance from one point (source-network) to one target using the source and target columns in the network. Using the following query:

```
    with subset as (
SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost
  FROM pgr_dijkstra(
    'SELECT gid as id, source, target, st_length(geom) as cost FROM roadnetwork,
    473384, 440012, FALSE, False
  ) as di
)
select sum(cost)::decimal (8,2) from subset
```

But how can I calculate multiple sources to multiple target? So in the query above I want the numbers 473384 and 440012 to be ‘flexible’.

Or is there any other way to calculate this?

Hope someone can help me with this problem

Comment: You might want to use pgr_kDijkstra as answered in   http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74564/calculating-many-shortest-paths-with-pgrouting/74603#74603 already.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have looked at pgr_kDijkstra, but still: how can you calculate multiple sources to multiple targets. Do you perhaps have an example query?

Comment: You could paste your query into stored procedure with source and target as input and cost as output... then use it to update table with your points, or sth

Comment: I'm wondering this too, as in: how can the pgr_kDijkstra function be used in the way the ST_Distance function is implemented... now THAT would be huge!

Comment: @Jendrusk, I am not familiar with stored procedures (functions). I will do some reading and experiment and hope I will figure it out.

Comment: @mapBaker, that would indeed be a useful function.

Comment: @Stefan - write about it (stored procedures) - it's not difficult and can resolve lots of problems - it will not be lost time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function code could be (it's an example - did not check if it's working) :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION give_me_cost(source integer, target integer)
  RETURNS decimal(8,2) AS
$BODY$
with subset as (
SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost
  FROM pgr_dijkstra(
    'SELECT gid as id, source, target, st_length(geom) as cost FROM roadnetwork',
    $1, $2, FALSE, False
  ) as di
)
select sum(cost)::decimal (8,2) from subset

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE;
```

Then you can use it in another select:

```
Select
 source_id, targer_id, give_me_cost(source_id, targer_id) as cost
from
 sometable
```

Comment: Niccce. Thanx 4 feedback :)